# Right treatment of getting the POST method information in the same page

Tags: php, html, web

I am not sure if i am treating my *"same page"* forms in a good way.
The way i am doing, is adding a hidden input called **"action"** with `value='1'` to my form.
And then, in the beggining of the page, i verify if the `$_POST["action"]` has a value, if it does, then i run the code.

I don't know if this is the right way. If there is any other way to do that, i will be greatful to know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually just give the submit buttons different names/values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to detect a POST request is:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // ... deal with $_POST parameters
}
```

You should not only check for the request method; Always validate the users input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it the right way.

I actually prefer using the hidden field more. It allows you to keep different POST types separate from one another.

Suppose I had a page that had two separate forms, one for login and one for registration. You could have a hidden field for login called `$_POST['login_submit']` and another for `$_POST['register_submit']`. Of course they would both be validated differently. This method, for me personally, provides better code readability.

**Example:**

```
if ( $_POST['login_submit'] )
{
    validate and do something...
} 
elseif ( $_POST['register_submit'] )
{
    validate and do something else...
}
```